# TypeError: Cannot read property 'any' of undefined after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, typeerror, babeljs

I updated several `npm` packages in my application and encountered a bunch of errors that I had already safely solved except for one!

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'any' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cpt/Desktop/prod/local/app/components/Base/react-quick-return.js:11:24)
at loader (/home/cpt/Desktop/prod/local/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
```

In the following code:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import detectPassiveEvents from 'detect-passive-events';
import {getScrollTop, getSupportedCSSProperty} from 'utils/dom';
import cx from 'classnames';

const EVENTS = ['scroll', 'resize', 'load', 'pageshow'];

class QuickReturn extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        component: PropTypes.any.isRequired, //HERE IS
        className: PropTypes.string
    };
```

I changed the `react` version from `15.3.1` to `16.8.4`

However, I also updated the following packages:

```
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "15.6.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.6.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-maskedinput": "4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "5.1.0",
    "react-router": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
```

As far as I can see, the problem is in the `babel-register` module, but it is not in my `package.json`

Tell me, please, what could be the matter? I got to the 5th page of Google, and decided to write here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PropTypes` don't live inside react proper any more. Now it's `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
Cannot read property 'any' of undefined
```

refers, as you have found on your own, to this line:

```
component: PropTypes.any.isRequired, //HERE IS
```

This means that `PropTypes` is `undefined`, and this in turn is because `PropTypes` has not been imported correctly. You try to do it with

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
```

but for quite some time now `PropTypes` is not part of React itself any more, but rather a separate package you need to install and import on its own. See [prop-types on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) for more details.

Basically, what you need to is to add the following line (and remove `PropTypes` from your existing `react` import):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```